# Difference between Purchase and Procurement

Tags: confusables

I found many people use "Purchase" and "Procurement" interchangeably.

Are they same?

If "No" then what are the differences between them and can you please provide two different examples to show where to use what.

Comment: Have you look up those words in a dictionary? See also: [ell.se]

Answer (score 3):

A purchase will involve paying for something. Procurement doe snot *have* to involve paying for it. So if you pay for it, the two are more or less interchangeable. If you don't pay for it, it is not a purchase.

Answer (score 3):

While they are often used interchangeably, 'procurement', from 'procure' has a wider meaning than purchase.

*Procure*, at its simplest, means 'to obtain'. In *Go down to the beach and see if you can procure a round stone*, there is no suggestion of money being paid as would be the case with 'purchase'.

'Procure' is also often used for 'persuade or cause someone to do something' e.g. *He procured his wife to sign the mandate*.

'Procurement' is frequently used to mean 'purchase' but in its very widest sense; including the identification and assessment for suitability of something e.g. *military and defence procurement*. This can also be applied to the work of commercial procurement. But everyday 'purchasing' by individuals is seldom described as 'procurement', certainly not for something as mundane as nipping out to the shop to buy a newspaper and a litre of milk. 'Purchase', would be far more suitable.